# npm install bitcoin-receive-payments --save

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04

I write the terminal:

```
npm install bitcoin-receive-payments --save
```

But only install two folder: node_modules and package-lock.json. I'm expecting the command install all js file. Why did not install ?

[open my file explorer ^image^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNRx2.png)

Answer (score 0):

It should have been installed in the node modules folder, to use it in your app you will now want to require('bitcoin-receive-payments') in the files in which you wish to use it.

ie.

```
    const BitcoinGateway = require('bitcoin-receive-payments')
const gateway = new BitcoinGateway(pub_key, openexchangerates_key)
```